# PHP submit multiple forms with 1 button

Tags: php, html

I want to submit multiple forms with only 1 buttons outside all of the form.
This is the index.php

```
 <form id="allform" class = "NameInput" action="addToCartFood.php" method="POST">
            Name:   <input type="text" class = "inputName" name="Name" value=""><br>
 </form>

 <form id="allform" action="addToCartFood.php"  method="POST">
            Date:       
            <select name="Date" class = "Date">
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
            </select>
            July 2020
</form>
<form id="allform" action="addToCartFood.php" method="POST">
            Adult:      
            <select id = "selectboxAdult" name="Adult" class = "Adult" onchange = "calculateAll(<?php echo $_SESSION['price'];?>)">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
</form>

<input  type="submit" class = "submitbtn" form="allform" value="Add to Cart">
```

And when i click the button, it will go to the addToCartFood.php and these are the codes

```
$_SESSION['Date'] = $_POST['Date'];
$_SESSION['Name'] = $_POST['Name'];
$_SESSION['AdultQ'] = $_POST['Adult'];
$_SESSION['KidsQ'] = $_POST['Kids'];
$_SESSION['telnum'] = $_POST['telnum'];
$_SESSION['comment'] = $_POST['comment'];
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you have multiple forms

Comment: Aside: Is there a real need to transfer raw values to session variables?  Or use sessions at all? Personally I try and keep session data to a minimum - token like data.

Comment: I used multiple forms so i could do css easily (?) but i think thats not a good idea based on the answers lol. For the session, i want to print all the values to the cart page. Is there any easier way?

Comment: you'd better use `<div>` instead of `form` to wrap fields, and then apply CSS for wrapping div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why multiple forms ? just merge them all in one form only as action and method is same for all

```
<form id="allform" class = "NameInput" action="addToCartFood.php" method="POST">
            Name:   <input type="text" class = "inputName" name="Name" value=""><br>
            Date:       
            <select name="Date" class = "Date">
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
            </select>
            July 2020
            Adult:      
            <select id = "selectboxAdult" name="Adult" class = "Adult" onchange = "calculateAll(<?php echo $_SESSION['price'];?>)">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>

<input  type="submit" class = "submitbtn" form="allform" value="Add to Cart">

</form>
```